# Can't Assemble File on Linux (Wrong target?)

Tags: android, linux, assembly, native

I read an interesting post on Google's ProjectZero and wanted to test the exploit on my own device.
The exploit uses ROP, and to facilitate it's usage, the author of the exploit included a program which produced appropriate shellcode from a c file. To make everything *even* easier, he included a build.sh script, executable from linux. The script always fails to assemble a file called [entry.S](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=97233919908899347676)

The errors include:

> Error: no such instruction: `adr X0,TLS'

and

> entry.S:33: Error: alignment not a power of 2

as well as

> entry.S:19: Error: too many memory references for `mov'

this

> entry.S:82: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `d'

and

> entry.S:82: Error: bad expression

The full log file is [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=50812732495886944729). I wonder whether the assembler is compiling to the wrong wrong target and does not understand the code?
Thank you for the help!

Comment: [Here](https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.ch/2016/12/bitunmap-attacking-android-ashmem.html) is the ProjectZero post I was talking about.  I am using linux to assemble the code with GNU Assembler.

Comment: Please copy/paste `entry.S` and the log into your question. I'm not downloading a file from some shady hoster. It seems like you are trying to use an assembler for the wrong target.

Comment: Almost seems like you have ARM code being compiled and assembled with an x86 toolchain.